# How to create good topology without changing the flow

Tags: modeling, topology, geometry

Guys how do i make that top extrusion sharp without changing the flow of the lower part?

[image]

I want the green area to be sharp but without those creases below.

[image]

Comment: maybe add an edge loop, or use the Edge Split modifier, or add Crease to the Edge you want (N menu)

Comment: i want to tighten the sideways. adding a loop would sharpen everything. And no creasing doesnt work as expected

Comment: sorry I'm not sure about what part of your mesh you want to sharpen, if you're talking about the front vertical angle you can add an edge loop close to the top edge and move it far from the bottom edge, like this: https://zupimages.net/up/18/25/hz53.jpg

Comment: that isnt clean tho. Isnt there any other way of sharpening the top extension with, even with tris?

Comment: what do you mean when you say it's not clean? you can sharpen it further with a second edge loop and work it more precisely if you want, I think it's the best way to do what you want but perhaps someone will have a better idea: https://zupimages.net/up/18/25/w3so.jpg

Comment: the sharpness decreases gradually on moving downward in this process and that isnt what i am looking for. I guess modelling the top as a separate object is the only way to get the result now

Comment: I thought you wanted the sharpness only on the top: "how do i make that top extrusion sharp without changing the flow of the lower part?" was your question... if you want the bottom to be sharp as well, move the edges close to each others so that it will increase the sharpness all along... but I think I've missed something or you haven't been clear enough, anyway I don't think having a separate top is a good solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider applying subdivision modifier to the sphere so you have more vertices to work with and then extrude to top bit, it will make your model a bit higher on the vertex count but it let you manipulate the model more easily.

besides that check some tutorials about **edge flow** (there are a lot not blender related but when it comes to topology it doesn't matter what software you are using), I recommend **Arrimus 3D** he is amazing (https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSLLdTBwLMfTKWS56tOiQpw)

and the most important video on the subject .. https://vimeo.com/10941211 by Grant Warwick

hope it helps